# _ViewImports unable to resolve assembly containing custom tag helpers

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Built in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` work just fine, however, whenever I attempt to import custom tag helpers that I've built, I get the following error when debugging:

[image: tag-helper-error]

I've attempted to import both from a class built at the root of the asp.net core project, as well as a class built into a class library external to the asp.net core project. Here is the code related to the custom tag helper:

**RepeatTagHelper.cs (in ASP.NET Core Project Root)**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mvc_form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <repeat count-of-things="5">HTML</repeat>
    /// </summary>
    public class RepeatTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public int CountOfThings { get; set; }

        public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < CountOfThings; i++)
            {                
                output.Content.AppendHtml(await output.GetChildContentAsync(useCachedResult: false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RepeatTagHelper.cs (in .NET Core Class Library)**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace core_resources.TagHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <repeat count-of-things="5">HTML</repeat>
    /// </summary>
    public class RepeatTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public int CountOfThings { get; set; }

        public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < CountOfThings; i++)
            {
                output.Content.AppendHtml(await output.GetChildContentAsync(useCachedResult: false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml (when referencing tag helper defined in ASP.NET Core Project**

```
@using mvc_form
@using mvc_form.Models
@using mvc_form.Models.AccountViewModels
@using mvc_form.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, mvc_form
```

**_ViewImports.cshtml (when referencing tag helper defined in class library)**

```
@using mvc_form
@using mvc_form.Models
@using mvc_form.Models.AccountViewModels
@using mvc_form.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, core_resources.TagHelpers
```

I've added the full solution to [GitHub](https://github.com/JaimeStill/mvc-form)

Comment: Have you referenced the class library project from the web project?

Comment: I have: [project.json](https://github.com/JaimeStill/mvc-form/blob/master/src/mvc-form/project.json) line 49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current settings, the produced .dll file is named: `core-resources.dll`

So you need to register it this way:

```
@addTagHelper *, core-resources
```

Or define a custom `outputName` for the `core-resources` project:

```
 "buildOptions": {
        "outputName": "core_resources"
    },
```

And then use this new name this way:

```
@addTagHelper *, core_resources
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help! It was really confusing, because Visual Studio replaced the dash with an underscore in all of the namespaces, and all of the using statements in `_ViewImports` used the underscore convention. Guess I should probably just stick to PascalCase for naming. Been spending too much time in angular lately.